# Computing PCA with several large rasters

Tags: r, covariance, raster, pca

The script below has worked for me with the same data when computing pearsons correlation. I have recently adapted it to create a covariance matrix to input into a pca. I read on a forum that inputting a pre-created covariance matrix might avoid memory problems but that hasn't been the case for me. I get the following errors when running the covariance matrix:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In na.omit.default(cbind(x, y)) :
  Reached total allocation of 6141Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In na.omit.default(cbind(x, y)) :
  Reached total allocation of 6141Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In na.omit.default(cbind(x, y)) :
  Reached total allocation of 6141Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In na.omit.default(cbind(x, y)) :
  Reached total allocation of 6141Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to do this so I don't run into memory problems? If I'm completely off-base here with computing the covariance first that's fine. PCA is the only thing I need in the end. My data are 12, 1-band raster in arcGIS's raster format and are large at 581.15 mb each. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)


setwd("K:/Documents/SDSU/Thesis/GIS Data All/GIS Layers/Generated_Layers/GridsForCor")


# List the full path to each raster:
raster_files = c('aspectclp',
                 'lakedistclp',
                 'ocdistclp',
                 'popdenclp',
                 'roaddistclp',
                 'scurveclp',
                 'sdemclp',
                 'solarradclp',
                 'sslopeclp',
                 'vegcatclp',
                 'canopcvrclp',
                 'canophtclp')

cov_matrix <- matrix(NA, length(raster_files), length(raster_files))
for (outer_n in 1:length(raster_files)) {
  outer_raster <- raster(raster_files[outer_n])
  # Start this loop at outer_n rather than 1 so that we don't compute the 
  # same covariance twice. At the end of the loops cov_matrix will be upper 
  # triangular, with the lower triangle all NA, and the diagonal all NA 
  # (since the diagonal would all be 1 anyway).
  for (inner_n in (outer_n):length(raster_files)) {
    # Don't compute correlation of a raster with itself:
    if (inner_n == outer_n) {next}
    inner_raster <- raster(raster_files[inner_n])
    cov_matrix[outer_n, inner_n] <- cov(outer_raster[], inner_raster[], 
                                    use='complete.obs', method = "spearman")
  }
}

pca_matrix <- princomp(raster_files, cor = FALSE, covmat = cov_matrix))

# Writing to a txt file & csv file
write.table(pca_matrix, "PCA.txt", sep="\t", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(pca_matrix, "PCA.csv") enter code here
```

Comment: Two somewhat tangential questions: (1) Why are you passing the vector of file paths to `princomp`? (2) Why are you using `princomp` rather than `prcomp`?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to use princomp or prcomp. I went with princomp because it gives the option of adding in a covariance matrix (something that I read might make it not run out of memory. Not true though, I guess?). And I'm not sure what to put in for x then since my files are too big to read into memory. In essence, there are many problems, some of which stem from my naivete with R :(.

Comment: I should also mention that I tried to put all of the rasters into a raster brick to use as the input to princomp or prcomp, but they were too large.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but have you checked out the bigmemory package?  It creates file backed matrices.  You could probably create matrices of your rasters, then run the calculations?  There's a working code from Hijmans at the following link, which creates a bigmatrix from a raster: http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/convert-Raster-object-to-bigmatrix-object-td6668252.html

Comment: First of all, making a covariance matrix will not help you with memory problems if your object has more columns than rows. Second, making a covariance matrix also creates another (possibly) large object, which is using up RAM. Are you using a 32-bit R build? Are you able to use a 64-bit build? That may help.

Comment: vitale232, thanks for the suggestion, I will look into bigmemory. Marc in the box, yes I'm using the 64-bit and will definitely be scratching building the covariance matrix then. Thanks!

Comment: Update: still haven't had any progress with figuring this out. Apparently big memory hasn't been updated for my version of R yet (2.15.2) so that's not an option unless I want to download and earlier version. Also, here's the link to the post about using the covariance matrix: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2012-February/014290.html. Maybe this would actually work if I calculated the matrix in chunks as suggested?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar difficulties doing pca on an ffdf object. Try inserting a `gc()` in your (inner) loop like this:

```
for (inner_n in (outer_n):length(raster_files)) {
  # Don't compute correlation of a raster with itself:
  if (inner_n == outer_n) {next}
  inner_raster <- raster(raster_files[inner_n])
  cov_matrix[outer_n, inner_n] <- cov(outer_raster[], inner_raster[], 
                                use='complete.obs', method = "spearman")
  gc()
}
```

This forces immediate garbage collection which can free enough memory for the `for` loop to proceed - at least for me that was enough for it to work.